# Laravel Eloquent fetching and displaying Customer Orders on Page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

There are 3 tables. First one is orders:

After example order:

[image]

```
class Order extends Model
{
   // Table Name
   protected $table = 'orders';

   // Primary Key
   public $primaryKey = 'id';

   // Timestamps
   public $timestamps = true;

   public function user() {         
       return $this->belongsTo('App\User');   
   }

   public function orderproduct() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\OrderProduct');
   }
}
```

Second one is OrderProduct table:

[image]

```
class OrderProduct extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'order_product';

    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function order() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Order');   
    }

    public function product() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');   
    }
}
```

Third one is products table:

[image]

```
class Product extends Model
{
    // Table Name
    protected $table = 'products';

    // Primary Key
    public $primaryKey = 'id';

    // Timestamps
    public $timestamps = true;

    public function orderproduct() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\OrderProduct');
    }
}
```

I am not sure with the relations.

What I am trying to do is: after user places an order, how do I write the correct eloquent query to display the order user has placed with the product he ordered? I mean I am redirecting user to their orders page after they place an order, right there I want to show their order details.

Edit:
I reach user id with this: auth()->user()->id 
Now with using this id i can reach order_date from first table.
Orders id is foreign key (order_id) in orderproduct table.

From second table take quantity and using product_id in second table reach information of product(name,img,price...)

So in the end i would like to display 
Order ID      Ordered Products Name  Ordered Products Img  Quantity of product ordered  Order Date   Paid Money(Quantity x price)

Comment: I'd recommend you create a [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship between Product and Order (and inverse as well). Then you'd just do `Order::with('products')->find($placedOrderId)`

Comment: try to use man-tomany relations

Comment: You can use `{{$order->name}} and @foreach ($order->orderproduct() as $product) {{$product->product->name}}@enforeach`

Comment: @devk should i add  public function product(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');

}            to Order.php    and    public function order(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order');

    }    to product.php ?